# Cannot select a range

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm writing a VBScript to recursively convert every CSV in a folder into xlsx files. I want to separate the data in those xlsx files according to the delimiter in the CSV files.

The relevant code is the following:

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.open(srccsvfile)
Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet1.Activate
objWorksheet1.Range("A:A").Select
MsgBox Selection '<<< Here the MsgBox is empty
Selection.TextToColumns objWorksheet1.Range("A1"), xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, False, False, False, False, False, True, "|"
```

My problem is that the function `TextToColumns` does nothing because `Selection` is empty.

How to fix this issue?

(The script is executed from a .vbs file, not from the Excel debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support implicit objects like VBA, hence your `Selection` is just an undefined variable. Without the `Option Explicit` directive undefined variables are auto-initialized with an `Empty` value, which is automatically converted to an empty string in the `MsgBox` call.

You need to specify the object that provides you with the [`Selection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property.

```
MsgBox objExcel.Selection
```

Doing this should give you a type mismatch error, though, because a range can't be cast to a string. You need to use an appropriate property, e.g. [`Address`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.address.aspx):

```
MsgBox objExcel.Selection.Address
```

You should be able to call `TextToColumns` on the `Selection` property, though:

```
objExcel.Selection.TextToColumns ...
```

If you want to use a variable you can assign the selection to one like this:

```
Set selection = objExcel.Selection
selection.TextToColumns ...
```

Or, you can use the `TextToColumsn` method directly on the range without selecting it first:

```
objWorksheet1.Range("A:A").TextToColumns ...
```

Comment: Very instructive answer, thank you. Another problem I had was that I forgot to replace the "xlDelimited" and "xlDoubleQuote" constants by their value.